# Link in the latest blog post is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, typographical-error

The link in the latest blog post ([Stack Gives Back 2021](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/01/13/stack-gives-back-2021/)) is broken.

Link to Girls Who Code is supposed to contain the *href* value as:

```
https://girlswhocode.com/
```

but instead, its *href* value is:

```
http://$8,427 [Girls Who Code](https://www.girlswhocode.com/)
```

which results in a broken redirect.

Comment: Already mentioned in comments of a post related to the discrepancy in the donation sum: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375115/stack-gives-back-total-is-off-by-6-to-8#comment1249632_375115

Comment: A short post from a user with low reputation and the words "Link to Girls", but instead of spam it is genuine and useful. Well, color me surprised.

Comment: Makes me wonder: should problems with blog posts be reported on MSO? I mean I guess it is not off-topic since the description of what is on-topic is ambiguously things that have to do with the website, the blog falls in that category. But a blog can have its own replies where you can report goofs.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! I've also reported the isue via contact form on StackOverflow's contact us page and they said they will fix the issue shortly. It looks like that might be the right channel for communicating the issues related to blog for now. Obviously, those are not open for everyone to see though, which might be more problematic for duplicates. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: The issue appears to be fixed now.